# Add Claims to a sub class of ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

In my MVC application I have created two subclasses of the basic ASP Identity `ApplicationUser` class using [TPT inheritance](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt), and would like to add some Claims to the objects to allow me to easily display the properties from the sub classes in views.

I must be missing a simple trick / have a fundamental misunderstanding of the ASP Identity setup, but I can't see how to do this.

Adding Claims to the `ApplicationUser` class would be straightforward, but the `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method where you do this can't be overridden in the sub classes to allow me to do it there.

Is there a way to achieve this simply (as everything else with this set up is working nicely), or do I have to set up my two `ApplicationUser` subclasses to directly inherit from `IdentityUser`, and set up two lots of config for them both in `IdentityConfig.cs`?

The classes I'm talking about are as follows:

```
//The ApplicationUser 'base' class
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        // Add custom user claims here

        //** can add claims without any problems here **
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, String.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName)));I 

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyUserType1 : ApplicationUser
{
        [DisplayName("Job Title")]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

        //** How do I add a claim for JobTitle here? **
}


public class MyUserType2 : ApplicationUser
{
        [DisplayName("Customer Name")]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        //** How do I add a claim for CustomerName here? **
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make GenerateUserIdentityAsync a virtual method in ApplicationUser which would allow you override the implementation in your concrete types.

That's the cleanest option that I can see.

Comment: I'd like to add claims for properties within the two sub classes though, which wouldn't be available in the base class, sorry if I didn't describe that very well.

Comment: Yes I get what you mean. Could you make GenerateUserIdentityAsync virtual in the base class and then override in the concrete classes? Even better would be to make it abstract but I suspect you can't do this because ApplicationUser implements IdentityUser

Comment: Brilliant, yes of course that's it. I had it in my head that the `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` method was part of the IdentityUser interface and couldn't be changed, and I admit I've not used the virtual modifier in this way before (only abstract), so probably wouldn't have thought of this anyway, many thanks! (If you want to edit up your answer to suggest this instead, I'll accept and upvote it)